# Entropy and enthalpy in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, physical-chemistry

can somebody clarify the statement thermodynamics teaches that the loss of entropy by a freezing salt solution can be overcome at temperatures much below 0 degree C because the gain in enthalpy by freezing water rises when temperature goes down

Comment: thank you for your enlightening answer.But how is it that salt water higher entropy

Answer (score 1):

When comparing the two processes of salt water vs. water freezing it is important to note that both processes result in the same end product. When salt water is frozen, the salt is "squeezed" out in order to allow the ice crystals to pack together in a lattice. Therefore the final entropy of frozen salt water is not different than that of water. Following this reasoning, salt water undergoes a greater decrease in entropy than water since it starts off at a higher state of disorder.

In order for **any** process to occur, the total entropy of the surroundings and system must increase. Since entropy **decreases even more** when salt water freezes, the **entropy of the surroundings must increase even more** for salt water to freeze. The formula for the entropy change of the surroundings based of the enthalpy change of the system and temperature of the system is: -$\Delta$H/T (Note $\Delta$H is negative). Furthermore, the enthalpy change between the two processes is no different (contrary to your assumption): in the salt water solution, only the water undergoes an energy change when it goes from solid to liquid, (negligible enthalpy change for salt). In order for entropy of the surroundings to increase, and knowing that -$\Delta$H does not vary between processes, the **temperature at which salt water freezes must be lower** to allow the total entropy change of the system and surrounding to increase.

Clarification: Salt water is more disordered because when you have a heterogeneous collection of particles it has more possible states. The more possible states, the greater the entropy. If I have two identical objects and two positions, there is only one possible state. If I have two different objects and two positions, there are two possible states.

Comment: @Harihanan V I just made an account and my reputation does not allow me to reply directly to your comment. If you could verify this answer as correct, I could respond more appropriately. Salt water is more disordered because when you have a heterogeneous collection of particles it has more possible states. The more possible states, the greater the entropy. If I have two identical objects and two positions, there is only one possible state. If I have two different objects and two position, there are two possible states.

Comment: How can there a gain in enthalpy by freezing water when the temperature goes down Instead there should be loss of enthalpy Will you please elaborate this

Comment: How does that contradict with the answer?

Comment: That's why H is negative

Comment: Also could you please verify my answer? It would really help me and I did spend a lot of time trying to answer it :(.

Comment: I am still confused.Will there be gain in enthalpy at low temperature

Comment: No, it is clearly states that H is negative, which means enthalpy is negative. I will not be responding anymore as you have not even verified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the assumption that entropy has decreased with the addition of salt, there are more micro states because of the salt ions.  the net entropy would be greater than water alone.  make an assumption that this occurs spontaneously, this would require heat to be released from then system.  if heat is released, it needs to go somewhere, and that would be the surroundings.